# Nested async loop pushing to a async queue not calling main callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a async queue that I am pushing to which will do something. The way I generate the items that I need to push into the is by going through a few nested lists form a data object. The queue ends up processing everything but for some reason I can't get to my main callback with the `console.log('All done.')`. I've remove most the the unnecessary stuff and just left async stuff. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

```
var q = async.queue(function(task, callback) {
  console.log('hello ' + task);
  callback();
}, 2);

function A(data) {
  B(data, function() {
    // THIS ISN'T getting called. 
    console.log('All done.');
  })
}

function B(data, callback1) {
  var list = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
  async.each(list, function(item, callback1) {
    async.each(item, function(i, callback2) {
      doWork(i, function() {
        console.log('Work done');
      })
      callback2();
    }, 
    // THIS should be called when everything in this each is done. 
    callback1)
  })
}

function doWork(i, callback3) {
  q.push(i, callback3);
}
```

Comment: To help clear up the question: What output are you getting? What were you expecting? Where is the code that calls A and B?

Comment: All the 'hello' + tasks and the 'Work done' are printing out. But only the main 'All done.' isn't.

Comment: please fix your code snipped so at least it's syntactically correct, otherwise it's really difficult to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code with some comments, as talking about callbacks of callbacks is a bit complicated:

```
function B(data, callback1 //this is what you want to be called) {
  var list = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];

  //async1
  async.each(list, function(item, callback1 //now callback1 is a function passed to your code by `async.each` not the original callback1) {
      //async2 
      async.each(item, function(i, callback2) {
      doWork(i, function() {
        console.log('Work done');
      })
      callback2();
    }, 
    // THIS is actually called, it's just a different function than you think it is 
    callback1)
  })
}
```

The problem is that you used the same name for both the argument of `B` and the callback argument of async1 callback function.

So the `callback1` inside async1 callback hides the external `callback1` and is actually the internal async1 callback which serves to pass control back to the `async.each`.

Solution is simple: rename the async1 callback parameter, for example:

```
function B(data, callback1) {
  var list = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];
  async.each(list, function(item, async1_callback) { //here lies the rename
    async.each(item, function(i, callback2) {
      doWork(i, function() {
        console.log('Work done');
      })
      callback2();
    }, 
    // this is now called as expected 
    callback1
    ); 
    // BUT we forgot to call the async1_callback, so let's do it:
    async1_callback();

};
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that... But the other issue is that it's coming out with the 'All done' first - it should come out last when the loop is done right? Am I missing something else?

Comment: It was still missing a call to async1_callback() - check the update. As for 'All done' being printed first - it's probably because neither async.each nor queue operations call process.nextTick anywhere and your code doesn't yield to the event loop. As for printing only once - just add it as the final callback to the async1, not async2